# Can access websites from different accounts of same hosting company

Tags: hosting

This is quite a weird issue I'm facing, something I've never even heard of.

I have 2 hosting accounts on liquidweb's servers. Both shared. At home, I'm not able to access sites on one account. At work, I'm not able to access the sites on the other account. Both work and home have the same ISP.

When I can't access, the multiple browsers I've tested on just can't connect, with the error "Failed to connect". Everything else works just fine. Pinging also times out.

I'm using a macbook pro if it helps.

Comment: That sounds like something you might want to take up with the hosting company.

Comment: Mailed them a ticket. Lets see how this goes. Looked too silly to ask them in the first place.

Comment: It might not be, but does sound a bit strange. Being that you can connect at one location but not another. If you find out any more info post it back here. Out of interest when you say "Failed to connect" are you attempting to just view a website normally or are you attempting to login to your providers cPanel or similar?

Comment: Both. I can however access both the admin billing panel's, but definitely not the cPanel.

Comment: Thats the sort of response I get when my server is either offline (turned off by me) or when my provider is having issues.

Comment: Hmm... It seems there is an issue with your DNS. I would recommend you to check it with your hosting provider. If you cant ping your domain, I believe it is the DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Spoke to the support. Apparently my ip's were blacklisted by their firewalls when I failed to login in to the cPanel after a few attempts. And ironically, I'd forgotten them at home, and workplace seperately (thanks to my password app failing).

All sorted. Thanks for the trouble guys.

Comment: This is a little flustering. How do I choose the first answer by cosmicsafari as the correct one? No options or points next to it. Searched FAQ and other pages, but no solution.